# Right way to set OSM fullscreen

Tags: java, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm trying to set OSM fullscreen adding a `onTouchListener` on the `MapView`, calculating the time between touch down and up, and setting a `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`. but this is not working well since other views on the activity and some items of `ItemizedOverlay` type are triggering the `OnTouch`.

Well, i really tried to make this work this way, but everything i tried i had the same result. Other items in screen triggers the OnTouch. There is some other way to make a fullscreen OSM?

Don't know exactly what to show about my code, because it's very simple and explained above. But if needed, i post here.